# Entity inheritance: central table with common values + extended father entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hibernate-annotations

My schema looks like this:

[image: Schema]

My `NOMINATION` table holds common data between all 4 of my nominations.

I have 4 types of nominations:

1. Coworker Nomination
2. Team Nomination
3. Idea Nomination
4. Success Nomination

Now, as you can see I only have 3 of the 4 tables modeled, and that is because on this legacy data model the only data that the Coworker Nomination needs is in the Nomination table.

So basically I used `DiscriminatorColumn` on column `CATEGORY_CODE` to discriminate and made 5 entities, 4 which inherit from a main `Nomination` entity.

`Nomination` Entity -> `CoworkerNom`, `TeamNom`, `IdeaNom`, `SuccessNom`.

**I have two questions:**

**1. Why are my specific DAOs not fetching columns from their specific tables?** 
For example:

Nomination.java:

```
@Entity(name = "Nomination")
@Table(name = "NOMINATION")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="CATEGORY_CODE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 1)

public class Nomination extends AuditableEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NOM_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true,
            nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Transient
    protected NominationType type = null;

    //So on
```

IdeaNom.java:

```
@Entity(name = "IdeaNom")
@Table(name = "IDEA_NOM")
@DiscriminatorValue("I")

public class IdeaNom extends Nomination {

    @Column(name = "PURPOSE_INC", insertable = true, updatable = true,
            nullable = true)
    private Boolean purposeIncrease;

    @Column(name = "PURPOSE_SIMPLIFY", insertable = true, updatable = true,
            nullable = true)
    private Boolean purposeSimplify;

    //so on
```

AuditableEntity.java:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AuditableEntity {
    /**
     * The user who last updated this object. This object is lazy loaded, so
     * make sure a session is open
     */
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY /*optional = true*/)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UPDATED_BY", referencedColumnName = "EMP_ID",
            nullable = true)
    @Cascade(value = {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private Employee modifiedBy = null;
    /**
     * The last system update timestamp for this entity
     */
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_DATE", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedOn = null;

    //getters and setters
```

My findByAll method looks like this:

```
public List<T> findAll() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("findAll");
        }
        return currentSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass()).list();
    }
```

and my DAOs, basically inherit from `AbstractHibernateDAO` where this method is located. It goes like `AbstractHibernateDAO` -> `NominationHibernateDAO` -> `IdeaNomHibernateDAO`.

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'ACTUAL_SITUATION'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:632)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:778)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    ... 38 more
```

`ACTUAL_SITUATION` is an Idea_Nom column, so I'm guessing its stopping at the common columns from `NOMINATION` and not fetching the specific columns.

**2. How would I be able to obtain a list of all nomination despite their type? Can I run a generic DAO against the Nomination entity by itself? This might be a stupid question as I have mentioned I already have a `NominationHibernateDAO` but I'm just curious because so far my count method only returns specific counts based on the DiscriminatorColumn...**

Answer (score 1):

In `Nomination` you have not specified the Inheritance strategy, I think you should use JOINED strategy:

```
@Entity(name = "Nomination")
@Table(name = "NOMINATION")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Nomination extends AuditableEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "NOM_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true,
        nullable = false)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;

   @Transient
   protected NominationType type = null;

  ...
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="NOM_ID")
public class IdeaNom  extends Nomination { ... }
```

You should look at [Mapping Entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html)

(2) with JPA if you do a query on `Nomination` the root of the hierachy, like above:

```
select n from Nomination n
```

it is a polymorphic query, it loads also `Nomination` subclasses.

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Now I'm getting: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'UPDATED_BY'.` This belongs to `AuditableEntity` which the father entity `Nomination` inherits from. Can be seen up top on the snippet for `Nomination`.

Comment: added to my main post, i've used this entity as my skeleton entity and my other entities which i have tested their respective DAOs on work with it just fine...

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in hibernate [HHH-5102](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5102) with inheritance JOIN and MappedSuperclass.

Comment: I'm using Hibernate 3.6.7.Final, it says there it has been fixed after 3.5.1

Comment: please score up if you cannot answer so it gets more views :(